# Elastic search using tire gem on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, heroku

To run elastic search on my local machine, I need to run the following command

> sudo service elasticsearch start

then serve the project. If i do not, I get an error saying cannot connect to port 9200. I can't do anything other than register a user if this is not working.

When it's on Heroku, I get the cannot connect to port 9200, but obviously i can't run the command

> sudo service elasticsearch start

How can I solve this?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bonsai

Comment: use 'gem searchkick', it is best for elastic search

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll look into that.